# Firebase Emulator error: Could not find the ng executable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-tools

I followed the guide in firebase docs and at the step: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web?authuser=0&hl=en#5, I'm certain that I'm 100% sure I followed it correctly, but still, the error keeps appearing:
[image]
I tried to test if ng command was installed, and it was surely installed
my firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "friendlychat",
      "source": ".",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "frameworksBackend": {
        "region": "us-central1"
      }
    },
    {
      "target": "friendlychat",
      "source": ".",
      "frameworksBackend": {}
    }
  ],
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: *firebaser here* While for a different framework (Next.js instead of Angular), this seems similar: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6173. Our team is looking into recent changes that might have caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Angular is globally installed in your machine? If yes, you can continue to read this article. Else I recommend you to visit the official Angular site and get the latest version installed :)

This problem is caused due to the reason that npm is unable to find ng. There are few ways that we can follow to get rid of this error.

npm link @angular/cli

[Go here](https://medium.com/@angela.amarapala/ways-to-fix-bash-ng-command-not-found-7f329745795)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).